# visual studio c++ project cannot find .dll

Tags: c++, dll, autodesk, fbx

I have downloaded the Autodesk fbx sdk and trying to build a simple console app. I have added additional directories in Linker / General / Additional Library Directories like follows:

[image]

see the screenshot of the directory below. There are several libs that (I suppose) I should add in dependencies, and there's also the .dll file. It's release folder (debug is another available), for x86 architecture and for VS2017 which I am using.

[image]

Also, I have add dependencies like below and have included the standard include folder as specified in the Autodesk manual

[image]

The project builds fine but shows the following when run:

Cannot run code because libfbxsdk.dll could not be found...
But it is in the folder as you can see in the pic. Could you pls help?

Comment: you have to put dlls in the same folder as the application or change the PATH environment variable to include the folder containing the dlls

Comment: @AlanBirtles apparently I have no idea what I am doing. I have put the .dll into the .exe's folder and it's working now. Thank you a lot

Comment: @AlanBirtles if you will, fell free to post a short answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker settings have nothing to do with finding DLL files at run-time. If you want this SDK to be available to all programs - which without reason to do otherwise would be my recommendation - hit the start button and search for "environment", choosing "Edit environment variables for your account". Edit the value of the PATH environment variable (adding it if necessary) to include the directories where the DLLs are located.

If you only want it to be available to this particualr program (and you don't have any other custom DLLs that need to be found) you could also change the startup directory in the project properties to the directory where the DLL files can be found (the startup directory is one of the locations in the system search path).